# How to remove full file with extension and replace with '?'

Tags: .htaccess

I have see some website at the url display like this:

```
something.com/?id=NjKvuOpaZx
```

How the file and extension been removed?

```
something.com/send.asp?id=hash
```

to

```
something.com/?id=hash
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET /send.asp\? [NC]
RewriteRule ^ / [R=301,QSA]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteRule ^/?$ /send.asp [QSA,L]
```

The above would work. Please note that `/send.asp` should be the exact path to the file you wish to hide, relative to server's document root directory.

Comment: Is it only for get request only?

Comment: @VladikVenger The query `id=` is available only for GET requests.